# Repository of Code Snippets

Tags: c#, visual-studio-express, code-snippets

I'm just getting started with C# and often find myself going back to other projects and reusing some snippet of code in a new project.

Is there a good tool out there with which on can store all the little pieces of code they reuse again and again AND integrates with Visual Studio Express??

Comment: Doesn't Visual Studio Express already have a code snippets feature?

Answer (score 4):

Visual studio has the concept of code snippets, under the tools menu there is a code snippets manager.

Almost forgot, to bring up the code snipped menu in code press CRTL+K+S.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio Express is not legally extensible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Extensibility) so I doubt there is a tool you can purchase or download that will integrate. However, [snippy](http://www.codeplex.com/snippy) will help manage and create standard .snippet files for you, without integration.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may want to develop your own little framework that can be referenced by various projects.

Comment: Sure. I'd love to.  Sounds like a good idea.  What better way to learn? Thanks!